# Losing models between controllers while using ARC

Tags: cocoa, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I have two controllers that are delegates of each other, and I am using ARC. The first controller retrieves an NSMutableArray of model objects from a database and then holds them for use by other objects. I have tested to make sure it is retrieving the objects correctly.

The second controller is supposed to obtain the model array from the first controller for further processing, but the models often disappear in the meantime. I set this up in the first controller:

```
@interface FirstController : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *modelArray;
@end

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *modelArray; //I also tried (strong).


@implementation
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
    [modelArray addObjectsFromArray:[delegate MySQLQuery:@"SELECT * FROM reports" forModelObjects:@"Report"]]; //Delegate here refers to a third controller
    NSLog(@"FirstController: %ld", [modelArray count]); //Everything OK here
}

@synthesize modelArray;
```

But when I call this in the second controller:

```
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
    newArray = [delegate modelArray]; // Delegate here refers to FirstController
    NSLog(@"SecondController: %@", newArray);
```

output is as follows most of the time (though occasionally it works):

```
FirstController: 28
SecondController: (null)
```

It looks to me like ARC is deallocing modelArray in FirstController, but I don't how to stop it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't read through your question in detail, so I'm not going to post an answer, but you really shouldn't initialize newArray, then immediately set it to something else. You're just immediately throwing away the mutable array you created.

Comment: I'll bet you forgot to set the delegate. sending any message to nil returns nil. this would explain the behavior you see.

Comment: vikingosegundo, you are correct. The delegate was the problem. Thanks!